# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 61

Tags: java, xml, maven, gradle

I am trying to upgrade our gradle from version 0.9 to version 1.10. Our Java codebase builds successfully with gradle 0.9.

When I ran the gradle 1.10 version I run into the following errors

> Could not resolve g="xml-apis" module="xml-:me="*" type="*" ext="*" conf:1.0.2.
>     Required by:
>         com.my_org:projectName:unspecified > org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:2.2.8
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

When run with --stacktrace option I get the following detail error:

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 61: http://my_organization_artifactory.com/artifactory//g="xml-apis" module="xml-/me="*" type="*" ext="*" conf/1.0.2/me="*" type="*" ext="*" conf-1.0.2.pom

Now the artifactory website is hosting the xml-apis as one of the libraries. Am not sure how to fix this and proceed with the upgrade

Comment: As far as I can see they are not in build.gradle , They seem to be pointing to the library "xml-apis". It is an externally built library and am not sure what I can do these errors

Comment: Could you please provide a sample script that reproduces the error?